# Wrapping WMS across date line using GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, wms, sld

I am using GeoServer to serve a WMS version of the [Natural Earth 1:10m Country](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) shapefile.

I have everything working pretty well except that when it wraps around the dateline, there's an extra borderline in Russia and Antarctica:

[image: extra border in Russia and Antarctica]

I've read a few posts about how to deal with this in QGIS, but it seems like no matter what I do, there will always be a seam where GeoServer wraps the map.

Is there any way to get rid of these extra border lines like perhaps a way to selectively tell it not to draw a stroke between certain polygon vertices?

Comment: As per [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like statements of appreciation in your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoServer is drawing that line because it's in your data.

There is currently no way to eliminate that line automatically, but if you are willing to code or sponsor changes, the project is open to everyone's contributions.

In case you just want to get it done without code changes, I guess you can extract the polygon outlines, turn that into a line layer, eliminate the bits overlapping the dataline, and then paint the original polygons without border, and the modified lines on top of it, as simple lines.